# How to listen to new incoming mail Microsoft Graph?

Tags: javascript, python, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph to get email as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Is there a way where I can listen to new incoming mail instead of calling the GET api to fetch new mail every time?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) to use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/resourceNotifications",
  "resource": "/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages",
  "includeResourceData": true,
  "encryptionCertificate": "{base64encodedCertificate}",
  "encryptionCertificateId": "{customId}",
  "expirationDateTime": "2019-09-19T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "{secretClientState}"
}
```

Resources available for email are :

Changes to all messages in a user's mailbox:-
/users/{id}/messages

Changes to messages in a user's Inbox:-
/users/{id}/mailFolders('inbox')/messages

**Note: you will only get the notification for new emails but not the resource data in v1.0 endpoint , where as you can get the resource data by adding the property "includeResourceData": true.**

For more info , see the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Hope this helps

Thanks